# Why is my xampp shell not finding mysql as a valid command?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, windows, xampp, wp-cli

I'm trying to use wpcli on xampp on windows, and following this tutorial -> https://lmilosis.wordpress.com/2020/01/26/19/

My issue arises entering this command

```
wp core config --dbname=wpcli_testing --dbuser=root --dbpass= --dbhost=localhost --dbprefix=wp_
```

Which results in ->

```
'"mysql --no-defaults --execute="' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have added exactly the following to the end of my system environment variable `;C:\xampp\mysql\bin;C:\xampp\php`, but this has not helped the issue.

Comment: Did you add MySQL as an environment variable _after_ opening the terminal window? If so try closing your terminal window, open it again and give it another go.

Comment: Definitely tried that already thanks though!

Comment: Does your terminal recognize `mysql` as a command? Try running `mysql -V` and see what happens.

Comment: It does yes. It will let me run it with `mysql -u root -p` when I'm using my xampp shell